# self Many to many field adding when is not supossed to

Tags: python, django, web

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followers', blank=True)
```

So i have this table but when i add a user in the followers field, django also add the user in both ways. For example if i have an user called john and i want to follow a user called math. When john is added to the followers of math, math is also added to the followers of john. And i don't know why is that. Should i use other type of model?

Comment: Apparently the problem is with the many to many field. I try to make a new model with only a charfield and a many to many field with him self and the same happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `symmetrical=False,` in your m2m relation. and + sign at the end of related name.

```
followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, related_name='followers+', blank=True)
```